# HTML Help: Making a live quantity counter

Tags: html

Hey so at my work we have an event coming up where we kinda reserve seats for it. It's actually more for us to see how many people are coming to the event and for the people signing up to get an idea of how many seats are open. We want something extremely basic and easy. I will link our current HTML code to you. If you take a look at it you will see 4 "Services" with a quantity of 500 each. Then an option to select how many seats 1-10. We want the basic function of selecting how many seats you want and for what service then putting in your name, selecting "reserve seats". Then the counter would subtract how many seats you selected from that 500 number and keep that number updated for all to see. Then at 0 you wouldn't be able to select that service.

In my head its seems very easy, but I suck at HTML and have no idea how to actually implement that.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; utf-8" />
 <title>Wildwood Calvary Chapel - Easter Seat Request Form</title>
 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <font size=+4><p><center>Wildwood Calvary Chapel </center></p></font> 
 <font size=+3><p><center>Easter Service Seats 2017</center></p></font>
  <form action="#" method="post" name="ticketForm">
   <div><font size=+2>
              <center>SELECT A SERVICE BELOW:<center><ul></h4>
                <BR>
              
    <center><label for="Yellow"><input type="radio" id="Yellow" name="service_number" value="30" />
         Saturday, April 15&nbsp;6:00 PM&nbsp;&nbsp;(500 SEATS LEFT)&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label></center>
        <br>
       
       
        <center><label for="green"><input type="radio" id="green" name="service_number" value="31" />
         Sunday, April 16&nbsp;8:00 AM&nbsp;&nbsp;(500 SEATS LEFT)&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label></center>
        <br>
       
       
        <center><label for="blue"><input type="radio" id="blue" name="service_number" value="32" />
         Sunday, April 16&nbsp;9:45 AM&nbsp;&nbsp;(500 SEATS LEFT)&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label></center>
        <br>
       
       
        <center><label for="red"><input type="radio" id="red" name="service_number" value="33" />
         Sunday, April 16&nbsp;11:30 AM&nbsp;&nbsp;(500 SEATS LEFT)&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label></center>
        <br>
       
       </ul></center><br>
    </div>
  
  <center><table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="request">Number of Seats:</label>
   </td>
  <td><select id="request" name="request">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  
    <tr>
   <td>
    
   <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve Seats" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved with html. You will need server side storage. You can use javascript to update the number of seats after having sent something to the server and after having had a positive response. So you need to start scripting on the server side, which cannot be done with html.

I suggest learning php and javascript to solve this.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. We are trying to do this through squarespace which doesn't let you do php. But thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I know squarespace will allow some java script. Would there be any way to do this with java script and without php?

Comment: You will need server side scripting in order to update and retrieve data from a server. Squarespace doesn't offer that. You can inject javascript code, but Javascript doesn't have a way to store data in one central place. You can use javascript to retrieve from and send info to a server. But the server (with a database and scripting engine) should be there to provide accurate info. So... learn to code php and javascript and you are ready to do the job! (Or pay someone to do this for you...)